# How to find an explicit formula from a generating function

Tags: polynomials, generating-functions

Having read on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_trigonometry#Generating_functions) about generating functions,  I still don't understand what I can do with a generating function.

For example, if I want to compute the first spread polynomial, how can I do that from a generating function, such as these (taken from the Wikipedia article):

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty S_n(s)x^n = {sx(1+x) \over (1-x)^3 + 4sx(1-x)}.
$$

An exponential one:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty {S_n(s)\over n!} x^n = {1 \over 2} e^x \left [ 1-e^{-2sx} \cos\left (2x \sqrt{s(1-s)}\right )\right ] 
$$

Comment: Who confronts you with GF like this without giving you the background? -.-

Comment: @Raphael: I would guess that it comes from Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spread_polynomials#Generating_functions

Comment: In general, you can't always find an explicit formula from a generating function.  That's one thing that makes generating functions more useful than explicit formulas.

Comment: @ Raphael: It was just my curiosity

Comment: Ah, ok. Well, as Qiaochu says, getting coefficients from a GF can be very hard. It is often relatively easy to find asymptotics, though, e.g. via Residue Theorem and methods to find asymptotics for complex integrals, e.g. method of steepest descent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know what Taylor expansion is, then you should know that $S_n(s)$ in e.g.f. is just its $n$th derivative at zero. For the ordinary g.f., it's almost the same, except that you have to divide the derivative by $n!$.

Anyway, if you want to do more with g.f. than this, I strongly advise you to at least look at this [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function) page and perhaps even into the [generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) book, which in my opinion does a pretty good job of introducing g.f. to a beginner.

Comment: Thank you, I downloaded the book!

Comment: The reader of this answer may not know what a Taylor expansion is

Answer (score 2):

**HINT** $\quad\quad $ With $\rm\ \ \alpha\ =\ 1 - 2\ s + 2\ \sqrt{s^2 - s}\ \ $ we have

$$ \rm \frac{s\ x\ (1+x)}{(1-x)^3 + 4\ s\ x\ (1-x)}\ =\ \frac{\alpha}{4\ (x-\alpha)} +  \frac{\alpha'}{4\ (x-\alpha')} - \frac{1}{2\ (x-1)} $$

Answer (score 1):

Here it's easier to work with the exponential generating function.  You just need to find the Taylor series of each term on the RHS.  You already know the Taylor series of one term.  To find the Taylor series of the other term, use the fact that $\cos t = \frac{e^{it} + e^{-it}}{2}$.